# Change index.php in urls with .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want replace index.php in urls

my url example:

```
http://example.com/index.php/blog/foo
```

i need to be:

```
http://example.com/my.php/blog/foo
or
http://example.com/name/blog/foo
http://example.com/shop/blog/foo
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(blog/.+)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

try using sed

```
echo "http://example.com/index.php/blog/foo" | sed 's/index.php/my.php/'
```